# How to use CSS Modules with webpack in React isomorphic app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-modules

I am build an isomorphic app using react, react-router, express and webpack. Now I want to use css modules to import css.

I use `import './index.css'` in `index.jsx`, it works fine on client, but doesn't work on server rendering. The error is `Error: Cannot find module './index.css'`.

**components/index.jsx**

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import style from './index.css';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="login">
                 // ...
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default App;
```

**server/router/index.js**

```
import url from 'url';
import express from 'express';
import swig from 'swig';
import React from 'react';
import {renderToString} from 'react-dom/server';
import {match, RouterContext} from 'react-router';

import routes from '../../client/routes/routes';
import DataWrapper from '../../client/container/DataWrapper';
import data from '../module/data';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('*', async(req, res) => {
  match({
    routes,
    location: req.url
  }, async(error, redirectLocation, props) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message);
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.status(302).redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    } else if (props) {
      let content = renderToString(
        <DataWrapper data={data}><RouterContext {...props}/></DataWrapper>
      );
      let html = swig.renderFile('views/index.html', {
        content,
        env: process.env.NODE_ENV
      });
      res.status(200).send(html);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Not found');
    }
  });
});

export default router;
```

**webpack.config.dev.js**(for webpack-dev-server)

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var config = require('./config');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:' + config.webpackPort,
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/client/entry',
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/js',
        filename: 'app.js',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:' + config.webpackPort + '/public/js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development')
            }
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'react-hot',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, {
            test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|svg|ttf|eot)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using the [Isomorphic CSS style loader](https://github.com/kriasoft/isomorphic-style-loader) for Webpack in this case to render critical path CSS during server-side rendering.

Comment: @HiDeo Do you use react-router? Could you show me a demo maybe? I tried this loader but I have no idea how to handle the server side code.

Comment: Yes and there are many examples / starter, for example the [React Isomorphic Starterkit](https://github.com/RickWong/react-isomorphic-starterkit) use `isomorphic-style-loader`, `react-router` alongside  server-side React rendering.

Comment: Since you are using css modules you should take a look on isomorphic css style loader - it's step to ultimate isomorphic boosted app. But be prepared for bundling node server code with webpack

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using webpack to compile UI code for both client and server side in that case. Just set `target: "node"` in webpack config to produce bundle which can executed in Node environment.

Answer (score 0):

That article might help for compiling your server side code with Webpack: http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I
Especially on how to exclude `node_modules` with the `externals` key.

A very bare config might look like:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const rootDir = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');
const distDir = path.join(rootDir, 'dist');
const srcDir = path.join(rootDir, 'src');

const localStyles = new ExtractTextPlugin('local.css', { allChunks: true });

const nodeModules = fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
  .filter(dir => !dir.startsWith('.'))
  .reduce((acc, prop) => {
    acc[prop] = 'commonjs ' + prop;
    return acc;
  }, {});

const loaders = [
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    include: srcDir,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
    },
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    include: srcDir,
    loader: localStyles.extract(
      'style',
      'css?modules&localIdentName=[name]-[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
    ),
  },
  {
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: 'json',
  },
];


module.exports = {

  target: 'node',

  entry: {
    server: ['server/index'],
  },

  output: {
    path: distDir,
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },

  externals: nodeModules,

  module: {
    loaders,
  },

  plugins: [
    localStyles,
  ],

};
```

Another solution (Webpack free) could be to use [babel-plugin-css-modules-transform](https://github.com/michalkvasnicak/babel-plugin-css-modules-transform)
.